# CSS Universal selector (*) specificity

Tags: css, css-specificity

I'm trying to figure out why `.x` has higher specificity than `*.x` when the latter is expected to win.

Isn't `*.x` supposed to have a specificty of `0-0-1-1` (1 class, 1 tag) while `.x` is just a single class `0-0-1-0`?

Consider the following basic code:

```css
*.x { color: blue; }

.x { color: red }
```

```html
<p class="x">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, nam.</p>
```

It should be blue. To demonstrate an expected behaviour, I replaced `*` with another element (`p`):

```css
p.x { color: blue; }

.x { color: red }
```

```html
<p class="x">This time it works.</p>
```

Comment: The universal selector has a specificity of 0, 0, 0, 0 You can't see the * as a tag. In your case, both are equal ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) (`*`) has no effect on specifity, therefore the latter selector's styles will be the ones that are applied.

> An asterisk (*) is the universal selector for CSS. It matches a single
>   element of any type. Omitting the asterisk with simple selectors has
>   the same effect. For instance, *.warning and .warning are considered
>   equal.

Comment: I'm not following this. When I make a rule for *, it appears to take priority over all my other tag and class rules. I want it to contain default values for all elements, so I want it to have low priority!

Answer (score 2):

This is to be expected. The W3C spec says,

"
A selector’s specificity is calculated for a given element as follows:

- count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= A)
- count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and
  pseudo-classes in the selector (= B)
- count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the
  selector (= C)
- ignore the universal selector

"

Note the last bullet.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity