# Vue is changing the specificity of the "*" selector by adding the data attributes, how do I work around this?

Tags: css, vue.js, build

I normally reset all margins/paddings by adding

```
*, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

as first thing in the css, which is normally totally fine, as it gets overwritten by every upcoming selector.

Vue is actually adding data attributes to every single selector in the css, which breaks the specificity of the * selector.

```
[data-v-c9eed8c6], body[data-v-c9eed8c6] {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

As the element-plus css is imported before my general css, this is causing an "error" now, as the css from element-plus gets overwritten by this selector.

Not sure what I expect as an outcome, I guess Vue needs these data attributes for bindings. When searching for the "issue" I stumbled upon this article - [CSS Universal selector (*) specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643622/css-universal-selector-specificity) - but it was actually just the final hint, what my issue is.

**Edit:**
I just found this question - [random "data-v-*" attribute in Vue.js components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701312/random-data-v-attribute-in-vue-js-components) - where the answers says, that this attribute is only added when using scoped css, which is not the case for me, I am importing my general css within the css loader in my vue config

Comment: could you provide a reproducible code? replit.com for example. which vue & bundler versions?

Comment: I can't answer your question, and I know nothing about Vue, but isn't it redundant to have `*, body {}` when `body` is already included in `*`?

Comment: How exactly are you importing your CSS?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-grass-rhf9pl - it actually doesn't work 100% (not sure why) but it doesn't really matter, as it seems that the platform is serving it and not building it, so the data attributes are not added, so not sure, how i can create a reproducible code online (as i guess other platforms are working the same way)

@MoritzRingler the css is imported in the vue.config.js

`
css: {
  loaderOptions: {
    sass: {
      additionalData: '@import "@/assets/styles/_general.scss";',
    }
  }
},
`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you placed your styles into `<style scoped>`. Better make a separate CSS file for your global styles and import it into `main.js`.

Comment: sorry, i guess my edit was a bit too late - i am actually loading the general scss in the css loader within the vue config, if i load it in the main.js, the variables are not available within the other files